# Modify Javascript Button To Get All Children?

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-object, custom-button, standard-objects

I have a JavaScript button that sits on the `Opportunity Product` object. When clicked it creates a new record on a custom object called `Opportunity Product Mirror`, creating a record and copying the selected fields to that new record.

This process works great for each line item but it does require the user to have to go into each opportunity line item record and hit that button, which on some opportunities might be 20-50 line items.

I wonder if someone could help me/advise me if its possible to create a similar process from a button that sits at the opportunity level, when clicked it creates an `Opportunity Product Mirror` record for each line item on the opportunity? That would be a massive time saver for the users involved.

I have included the code from the current button below:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js")} 

var subMirrorId = '{!OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity_Product_MirrorId__c}'; 

if(subMirrorId == null || subMirrorId == ''){ 

    var oppProduct = new sforce.SObject("OpportunityLineItem"); 
    var oppProdMirror = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity_Product_Mirror__c"); 
    var mirrorLookup = '{!OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity_Product_MirrorId__c}'; 

    oppProduct.Id = '{!OpportunityLineItem.Id}'; 

    var queryRes = sforce.connection.query("Select UnitPrice, Quantity, TotalPrice, Product2Id, CurrencyIsoCode, SB_Quantity__c, Segment_Index__c, Description, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, OpportunityId From OpportunityLineItem Where Id = '" + oppProduct.Id + "' LIMIT 1"); 

    var records = queryRes.getArray("records"); 

    oppProdMirror.Quantity__c = records[0].Quantity; 
    oppProdMirror.Sales_Price__c = records[0].UnitPrice; 
    oppProdMirror.Opportunity_Product_Id__c = '{!OpportunityLineItem.Id}'; 
    oppProdMirror.Product__c = records[0].Product2Id;
    oppProdMirror.Opportunity__c = records[0].OpportunityId;
    oppProdMirror.Total_Price__c = records[0].TotalPrice;
    oppProdMirror.CurrencyIsoCode = records[0].CurrencyIsoCode;
    oppProdMirror.SBQQ_Quantity__c = records[0].SB_Quantity__c;
    oppProdMirror.Description__c = records[0].Description;
    oppProdMirror.Segment_Index__c = records[0].Segment_Index__c;
    oppProdMirror.Start_Date__c= records[0].Start_Date__c;
    oppProdMirror.End_Date__c = records[0].End_Date__c;

    var oppProductMirrorInsertRes = sforce.connection.create([oppProdMirror]); 


    if(oppProductMirrorInsertRes[0].getBoolean("success")){ 
        oppProduct.Opportunity_Product_Mirror__c = oppProductMirrorInsertRes[0].id; 
        var oppProdUpdRes = sforce.connection.update([oppProduct]); 

        if(oppProdUpdRes[0].getBoolean("success")){ 

            window.top.location.href = '/' + oppProductMirrorInsertRes[0].id 
        }else{ 
            alert('Error creating sub item container: ' + oppProdUpdRes[0]); 
        } 
    }else{ 
        alert('Error creating sub item container: ' + oppProductMirrorInsertRes[0]); 
    } 

}else{ 
    window.top.location.href = '/' + subMirrorId; 
}
```

I have an update on this. I've made some edits based on the advice below and I am now receiving a different error message:

[image]

For reference here is what my script now looks like:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js")} 

var subMirrorId = '{!OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity_Product_MirrorId__c}'; 

if(subMirrorId == null || subMirrorId == ''){ 

var oppProduct = new sforce.SObject("OpportunityLineItem"); 
var oppProdMirror = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity_Product_Mirror__c"); 
var mirrorLookup = '{!OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity_Product_MirrorId__c}'; 

oppProduct.Id = '{!OpportunityLineItem.Id}'; 

var queryRes = sforce.connection.query("Select UnitPrice, Quantity, TotalPrice, Product2Id, CurrencyIsoCode, SB_Quantity__c, Segment_Index__c, Description, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, OpportunityId From OpportunityLineItem Where OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}'"); 
var newRecords = []; 
var oppProdMirror = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity_Product_Mirror__c"); 
var records = queryRes.getArray("records"); 
for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) { 
oppProdMirror.Quantity__c = records[i].Quantity; 
oppProdMirror.Sales_Price__c = records[i].UnitPrice; 
oppProdMirror.Opportunity_Product_Id__c = '{!OpportunityLineItem.Id}'; 
oppProdMirror.Product__c = records[i].Product2Id; 
oppProdMirror.Opportunity__c = records[i].OpportunityId; 
oppProdMirror.Total_Price__c = records[i].TotalPrice; 
oppProdMirror.CurrencyIsoCode = records[i].CurrencyIsoCode; 
oppProdMirror.SBQQ_Quantity__c = records[i].SB_Quantity__c; 
oppProdMirror.Description__c = records[i].Description; 
oppProdMirror.Segment_Index__c = records[i].Segment_Index__c; 
oppProdMirror.Start_Date__c= records[i].Start_Date__c; 
oppProdMirror.End_Date__c = records[i].End_Date__c; 
newRecords.push(oppProdMirror); 
} 
var oppProdUpdRes = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 

var oppProductMirrorInsertRes = sforce.connection.create([oppProdMirror]); 

if(oppProductMirrorInsertRes[0].getBoolean("success")){ 
oppProduct.Opportunity_Product_Mirror__c = oppProductMirrorInsertRes[0].id; 
var oppProdUpdRes = sforce.connection.update([oppProduct]); 

if(oppProdUpdRes[0].getBoolean("success")){ 

window.top.location.href = '/' + oppProductMirrorInsertRes[0].id 
} 

else{ 
alert('Error creating sub item container: ' + oppProdUpdRes[0]); 
} 
} 

else{ 
alert('Error creating sub item container: ' + oppProductMirrorInsertRes[0]); 
} 

} 

else{ 
window.top.location.href = '/' + subMirrorId; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The basic change you need to make is to your query. Once you move this button to the `Opportunity` object, change:

```
"... From OpportunityLineItem Where Id = '" + oppProduct.Id + "' LIMIT 1"
```

To:

```
"... FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}'"
```

Note that you change the field from `Id` to `OpportunityId` and remove the `LIMIT` clause. You will also have to change your data types so that you have a list of mirror objects, but it should be pretty straightforward once you change the query.

Comment: That makes sense. What do you mean by " You will also have to change your data types so that you have a list of mirror objects'" ?

Comment: @user For instance, right now you have `var oppProdMirror = new sforce.SObject("...")`. Instead it would be `var oppProdMirrors = []` and then you would populate the array with individual mirror records.

Comment: thanks for replying. I know I'm being a pain but I'm still not quite sure what I'd need to edit in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var queryRes = sforce.connection.query("Select UnitPrice, Quantity, TotalPrice, Product2Id, CurrencyIsoCode, SB_Quantity__c, Segment_Index__c, Description, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, OpportunityId From OpportunityLineItem Where OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}'"); 
var newRecords = [];
var oppProdMirror = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity_Product_Mirror__c"); 
var records = queryRes.getArray("records"); 
for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
    oppProdMirror.Quantity__c = records[i].Quantity; 
oppProdMirror.Sales_Price__c = records[i].UnitPrice; 
oppProdMirror.Opportunity_Product_Id__c = '{!OpportunityLineItem.Id}'; 
oppProdMirror.Product__c = records[i].Product2Id;
oppProdMirror.Opportunity__c = records[i].OpportunityId;
oppProdMirror.Total_Price__c = records[i].TotalPrice;
oppProdMirror.CurrencyIsoCode = records[i].CurrencyIsoCode;
oppProdMirror.SBQQ_Quantity__c = records[i].SB_Quantity__c;
oppProdMirror.Description__c = records[i].Description;
oppProdMirror.Segment_Index__c = records[i].Segment_Index__c;
oppProdMirror.Start_Date__c= records[i].Start_Date__c;
oppProdMirror.End_Date__c = records[i].End_Date__c;
    newRecords.push(oppProdMirror);
}
var oppProdUpdRes = sforce.connection.create(newRecords);
```

Comment: Is this replacing a portion of the script?

Comment: @user3480962 I didn't add full code as rest of the code is same.

Comment: I thought that was the case but unfortunately I'm getting an error: "OppProductMirrorInsertRes not defined"

Comment: @user3480962 Did you miss declaring `OppProductMirrorInsertRes`?

Comment: i believe i have it in but I am getting a different error. I have updated my original post with the new script to you can see it in full. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @user3480962 The error says it all. You didn't specify Id in your update call. I think you need to create them.

Comment: @user3480962 Why do you again creating records. Is this line necessary? `var oppProductMirrorInsertRes = sforce.connection.create([oppProdMirror]);`.

Comment: I tried with and without that line, without that line i still get an error but a different one. I get the "OppProductMirrorInsertRes not defined"

Comment: @user3480962 modify line as `var oppProductMirrorInsertRes = sforce.connection.create(newRecords);` and remove line `var oppProdUpdRes = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);`. I don't know why you updating records and after inserting same records.

Comment: So this change has partially worked. I'm still getting an error appear but its also creating records. The only issue is that its creating the right number but only copying the last opportunity line item. So for example, if there are three line items when I click the button I get the error "oppProduct is not defined", then I refresh the page and it has created three opp product mirrors but they are all copies of the last line item and not one of each.